# How to get a list of keyboard shortcuts that I use for my macros?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

I know I can find a list of standard keyboard shortcuts of excel in google or through Microsoft Office Help. But I have overwritten some of them (I wasn't using them) to assign for some of my macros that I use often. Now I don't remember exactly which ones I had overrode and I don't want to overwrite any existing useful ones, either.

I try to execute a combination of shortcut to see if it is already in use and what it does. But depending on your file/data, testing it sometimes would do nothing, even though that particular combination of keys are already assigned as a shortcut, so it isn't a guarantee way.

Isn't there any place in excel that I can just get the list of the active keyboard shortcuts? Excluding QAT (Quick Access Toolbar) shortcuts, of course.

Comment: There are few possibilities,, `1.` create macro to link any standard URL all about KB Shortcuts, `2.` Link one self created PDF file contains KB Shortcuts with macro.

Comment: Hi Rajesh thanks for the answer, but I couldn't understand your offered solution? What do you mean by 'create macro to link any standard URL all about KB Shortcuts'.

Comment: As for 2nd solution, creating a manual list myself isn't a solution at all. I might have not been clear enough in my original post but issue here, I don't know if a certain combination of shortcut (let's say ctrl+sfht+T) has already something assigned to it, because as tried to explain above, not all macros would be applicable for a file that I try to test it to see. But even if I knew, doing such manual list for excel isn't a solution. It's like trying to use a calculator to sum up some numbers and punching it on a cell instead of using a SUM function. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: ,, you may Copy & Paste KB Short cuts in any PDF file and create Macro to open that PDF,, via Excel.

Comment: @RajeshS Please post that as an answer

Comment: Glad to help you @Ali Aksar check now I've posted an answer☺

Comment: Good solutions [on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16862306/2662901).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There are few possibilities:*

1. Create Macro to link any standard URL all about KB shortcuts.
2. Link a self created PDF file contains KB Shortcuts, with Macro.
3. *Copy* & *Paste* KB Short cuts in any PDF file and create Macro to open that PDF via Excel.